# AngularJS+reCaptcha: error "reCaptcha has not been loaded yet"

Tags: angularjs

I got `Error: reCaptcha has not been loaded yet.` when using google's `angular-recaptcha` package.

the `index.html` is as following, and it display fine to show recaptcha and a button to call `login` function in controller. and recaptcha works fine as well.

```
<div vc-recaptcha class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div>
<div ng-click="lc.login()">submit</div>
```

`app.js` is as

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('loginService', [
            'vcRecaptcha'
        ]);
})();
```

`controller` is as following, and the error is from here. it looks like I did not inject recaptcha module right.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('loginService.login.controllers')
        .controller('LoginController',
        ['$scope',
            'vcRecaptchaService',
            function ($scope, vcRecaptchaService) {
               var lc = this;
...
...
           function login() {
             if(vcRecaptchaService.getResponse() === "") // error is from here
 {...}

}]);
```

It looks that I do not inject recaptcha package in the right way. any one can help?

Comment: do you get this all the time or only sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded the library the following way?

```
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded" async defer></script>
<script src="./angular-recaptcha.js"></script>
<script>
        var app = angular.module('loginService', ['vcRecaptcha']);
        // code
</script>
```

Take a look at the example and the documentation:

- https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha/blob/master/demo/usage.html
- https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha

Add the `loginService` to the `loginService.login.controllers`

```
angular.module('loginService.login.controllers', ["loginService"])
```

Comment: for google library, I do not have `?render=explicit&onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded" async defer`, since it does not work in my page and I do not know why.

Comment: yeah, I already read the link above before asking the question.

Comment: I can display recaptcha widget success and it works fine. the problem is to get the response of it.  I use vcRecaptchaService.getResponse() as lots tutorial says, but it does not work and this is the reason I ask this question.